# Google Photos image cropping tool

Tags: android, image-processing

How to create image cropping tool like google photos application image cropping tool? I have searched everywhere, but didn't found any library or code which works like google photos cropping app.

I mean, this functionality of this app. I have found many libraries, but problem is that, when I add seekBar for image rotating, it is rotating hole view (image and cropping frame), I want, that the cropping frame don't rotate.

I tried this libraries https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45

[image]

here is my rotating code, and this is library https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop

```
private void rotateClick(){
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            imageView.setRotation(progress)
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```

and xml

```
 <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.soundcloud.android.crop.CropImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/crop_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/done_cancel_bar" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this awesome library, thanks creators :*
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3054

But this library is not exactly identical to the Google photos cropping tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to crop your image. Hopes it will help you.

```
 public static void copyFile(File src, File dst) {
    try {
        dst.createNewFile();
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(src);
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        FileChannel inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
        FileChannel outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("copy", "failed copy");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have cropping functionality. My only problem is that when I rotate the imageView, cropping frame were also rotating